# Use guava table

Tags: java, guava

It seems that the Guava Table can only store a cross table like:

```
Id year sales
1 2000 3000
2 2001 3045
3 2002 4000

table.put(1, 2000, 3000);
table.put(2,2001,3045); 
table.put(3,2002,4000);
```

If I have a table like

```
Id year month country provice sales
1 1999 1 US LA 3000
2 1999 2 IT MI 4000
3 2000 1 CH BJ 5000
```

And I can't use a JAVABEAN to store the recoder!

Answer (score 6):

That's not exactly how you are supposed to use a table. Each put corresponds to a cell - so in your first example, you would do something like:

```
table.put(1, "Year", 2000);
table.put(2, "Year", 2001);
table.put(3, "Year", 2002);

table.put(1, "Sales", 3000);
table.put(2, "Sales", 3045);
table.put(3, "Sales", 4000);
```

And your second example becomes, for example:

```
table.put(1, "Year", 1999);
table.put(1, "Month", 1);
table.put(1, "Country", "US");
table.put(1, "Province", "LA");
table.put(1, "Sales", 3000);
//etc.
```